# Even if I close target tag in ant also showing error. How can i fix target closing error in ant?

Tags: ant, build, build-process

I am using ant 1.7.1 version.my build.xml file is `

```
<target name ="target1" >

     <property name="javasrc" value="/Ant/java" />
     <property name= "javaclassdest"  value="/Ant/javaclass"/>

     <javac srcdir="${javasrc}" destdir="${javaclassdest}"/>
     <echo> creating jar</echo>
     <property name="jardest" value="/Ant/jar"/>
     <property name="jclass-src" value="/Ant/javaclass"/>

     <fileset dir="${javaclassdeest}" casesensitive="yes"/>
     <include name="**/*.class"/>
     <exclude name="**/*.png"/>
     </fileset>

     <jar destfile="${jardest}/app.jar" basedir="${jclass-src}"/>

 </target>
</project>
```

`

In build.xml file proper closed target `</target>` tag is there. but when I run with `ant` command it showing below error

```
`[root@ram Ant]# ant
 Buildfile: build.xml

 BUILD FAILED
 /Ant/build.xml:18: The element type "target" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</target>".

 Total time: 0 seconds
```

`
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: <project name="my 1st test project"  default ="target1"  >

    <target name ="target1" >

         <property name="jardest" value="/Ant/jar"/>
         <property name="jclass-src" value="/Ant/javaclass"/>

         <fileset dir="${jclass-src}" casesensitive="yes"/>
         <include name="**/*.class"/>
         <exclude name="**/*.png"/>
         </fileset>

         <jar destfile="${jardest}/app.jar" basedir="${jclass-src}"/>

     </target>

</project>

this is my simple build.xml

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in your `fileset` call: it ends with a trailing slash, remove it and it should work :

```
<fileset dir="${javaclassdeest}" casesensitive="yes">
    <include name="**/*.class"/>
    <exclude name="**/*.png"/>
</fileset>
```

Comment: thanks so much after posted i also found that . any way thanks for your valuable time and answer .

Comment: then ant have to thrown error like error in fileset . but instead of this it showing error in target tag . why don't ant update this showing proper error ?

Comment: actually, I think ant is showing proper error : ant build file must be a well formed xml file. When writing the starting tag `<target..>`, ant parser expect to found well formed children elements and this is the case for all children until line `</fileset>`. This latter is closing an xml element, but do not correspond to any pending opened tag: actually, the only pending opened tag is `<target...>` and so parser complains with error on finding a closing tag that do not correspond to the expected one (which is target).

Comment: yes i agree but my suggestion is if it return exact missing tag is better than return target .